# text to expression in function of variance estimation of derived parameters via Delta Method

Tags: r, eval

I have written a function to perform matrix multiplication on each row of the data set `pd.matrix`.  The function `my.var.function` performs as intended.  However, now I want to generalize the function to handle matrices of variable sizes instead of just the example matrix with five columns.

To generalize the function I imagine that I will need to replace `x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]` in the `apply` statement with something like `x[1]:x[ncol(pd.matrix)]`.  I imagine I similarly will need to replace the two instances of `(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)` within the function.

I have tried making these changes with `eval(parse(text=` followed by `paste0` to create the desired series of `x1, x2, x3, x4, x5` or `x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]` for this example.  However, I have been unable to get `eval(parse(text=` to work after trying numerous permutations.

How can I generalize the function and `apply` statement to handle a `pd.matrix` of `n` columns rather than five columns?

```
pd.matrix <- matrix(c(0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50,
                      0.11, 0.21, 0.31, 0.41, 0.51,
                      0.12, 0.22, 0.32, 0.42, 0.52,
                      0.13, 0.23, 0.33, 0.43, 0.53,
                      0.14, 0.24, 0.34, 0.44, 0.54), nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)

vcv.mat = matrix(c(0.01,   0.0020, 0.0030, 0.0040, 0.0050,
                   0.0020, 0.02,   0.0031, 0.0041, 0.0051,
                   0.0030, 0.0031, 0.03,   0.0042, 0.0052,
                   0.0040, 0.0041, 0.0042, 0.04,   0.0053,
                   0.0050, 0.0051, 0.0052, 0.0053, 0.05), nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE) 

my.var.function <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) {
     my.pd <- matrix(c(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5), nrow = 1)
     my.mat = my.pd %*% vcv.mat
     my.var = my.mat %*% t(my.pd)
     return(my.var = my.var)
}

apply(pd.matrix, 1, function(x) my.var.function(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]))
# [1] 0.0303160 0.0319642 0.0336588 0.0353998 0.0371872
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be very simple.  Not sure why I did not see this solution before.

```
pd.matrix <- matrix(c(0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50,
                      0.11, 0.21, 0.31, 0.41, 0.51,
                      0.12, 0.22, 0.32, 0.42, 0.52,
                      0.13, 0.23, 0.33, 0.43, 0.53,
                      0.14, 0.24, 0.34, 0.44, 0.54), nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)

vcv.mat = matrix(c(0.01,   0.0020, 0.0030, 0.0040, 0.0050,
                   0.0020, 0.02,   0.0031, 0.0041, 0.0051,
                   0.0030, 0.0031, 0.03,   0.0042, 0.0052,
                   0.0040, 0.0041, 0.0042, 0.04,   0.0053,
                   0.0050, 0.0051, 0.0052, 0.0053, 0.05), nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE) 

my.var.function <- function(x) {
     my.pd <- matrix(c(x), nrow = 1)
     my.mat = my.pd %*% vcv.mat
     my.var = my.mat %*% t(my.pd)
     return(my.var = my.var)
}

apply(pd.matrix, 1, function(x) my.var.function(x))
# [1] 0.0303160 0.0319642 0.0336588 0.0353998 0.0371872
```

Comment: even simpler, `diag(pd.matrix %*% vcv.mat %*% t(pd.matrix))`

Comment: Excellent response.  Will up-vote and probably accept if you post that as an answer.  Perhaps I should change the title of the question since the answer did not involve `eval`.

Comment: no worries, you can just add it to your answer if you're inclined.  Just glad you aren't trying to `eval(parse` function arguments :)

Comment: bunk's is even shorter but note that the `apply` at the end of the answer can be written as `apply(pd.matrix, 1, my.var.function)`